# I want to place five imagebuttons horizontally, but when I do I only get 4 buttons in some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imagebutton

Is there a way where I can see all 5 ImageButtons in same column? I am working on a calculator app and it has 5 columns and 6 rows. Even though am getting 5 buttons in some devices I am not getting all buttons on screen on small devices. Is there any possible way to do this? This is the xml I am working on.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStack"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="txt stack"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="text input"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMemory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="for memory"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_mc" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_mr" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_ms" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_m_plus" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_m_minus" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use weight in the following way

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:weightSum="5"  >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_mc"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_mr"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_ms"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_m_plus"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_m_minus"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works

Comment: But in big screens the gap between buttons is too large and buttons looking small.Any idea how to fix that???

Comment: M not sure but try using android:background="@drawable/button_m_plus" and android:scaleType="fitXY" for your imageView.

Comment: It worked and a lot better than b4 but in tablets and in large displays its stretching horizontally and vertically no change . Any idea how to dynamically change the buttons regardless of the screen size???

Answer (score 0):

If you put the 5 images horizontally, one may run off the screen. I would suggest putting the images in a scrollview if you are having that problem.

Comment: no need for scrollview... by using weightsum its working fine as expected.